# Cylindrical Projection - how to get y image coordinates from tangens(latitude)

Tags: dictionary, projection

I need to implement a transformation from geographic coordinates with hight data to a image.

Like described in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalProjection.html.

I simply don't know how to create the suitable y-value...

For example:

```
   double longitude   = -180; // (λ)   
   double latitude    =  80;  // (φ)   
   int mapHeight   = 360;   
   int mapWidth    = 720;   
   x = (int)((longitude+180.0)*(mapWidth/360.0));
```

How do i use the results of

```
 Math.tan(Math.toRadians(latitude))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can not represent the poles using a cylindrical projection. So you need to set a maximum latitude and store it (say `double maxlat=3.1415/2.0`). To get `y`, first, test if the point is not to close to the poles, then compute :

```
  y=(int)(mapHeight/2+mapHeight/2*Math.tan(Math.toRadians(latitude)) /Math.tan(Math.toRadians(maxlat))) ;
```

If you are looking for a beautiful map, consider using the Mercator projection :

```
 y=(int)(mapHeight/2+mapHeight/2*Math.log(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(latitude)/2.0+M_PI/4.0)) /Math.log(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(maxlat)/2.0+M_PI/4.0))) ;
```

Store `Math.tan(Math.toRadians(maxlat))` or `math.log(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(maxlat)/2.0+M_PI/4.0))` if you need to compute many points

Comment: Thank you very very much for your quick and helpful answer!

/Math.tan(Math.toRadians(maxlat)) was my missing part.

I know that Mercator is a way better map projection than the standart cylindrical and i already have an implementation of it (i had to implement 3 diffent projections).